# fargate failing on docker pull in private subnet

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I am having trouble deploying a fargate cluster, and it is failing on the docker pull image with error "CannotPullContainerError". I am creating the stack with cloudformation, which is not optional, and it creates the full stack, but fails when trying to start the task based on the above error.

I have attached the cloudformation stack file which might highlight the problem, and I have doubled checked that the subnet has a route to nat(below). I also ssh'ed into an instance in the same subnet which was able to route externally. I am wondering if i have not correctly placed the pieces required i.e the service + loadbalancer are in the private subnet, or should i not be placing the internal lb in the same subnet???

This subnet is the one that currently has the placement but all 3 in the file have the same nat settings.

subnet routable (subnet-34b92250) 
* 0.0.0.0/0 -> nat-05a00385366da527a

cheers in advance.

yaml cloudformaition script:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Cloudformation stack for the new GRPC endpoints within existing vpc/subnets and using fargate
Parameters:
  StackName:
    Type: String
    Default: cf-core-ci-grpc
    Description: The name of the parent Fargate networking stack that you created. Necessary
  vpcId:
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-0d499a68
    Description: The name of the parent Fargate networking stack that you created. Necessary
Resources:
  CoreGrcpInstanceSecurityGroupOpenWeb:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupName: sgg-core-ci-grpc-ingress
      GroupDescription: Allow http to client host
      VpcId: !Ref vpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  LoadBalancer:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer'
    DependsOn:
      - CoreGrcpInstanceSecurityGroupOpenWeb
    Properties:
      Name: lb-core-ci-int-grpc
      Scheme: internal
      Subnets:
      # # pub
      #   - subnet-f13995a8
      #   - subnet-f13995a8
      #   - subnet-f13995a8
      # pri
        - subnet-34b92250
        - subnet-82d85af4
        - subnet-ca379b93
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
          Value: '50'
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref CoreGrcpInstanceSecurityGroupOpenWeb
  TargetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    DependsOn:
      - LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: tg-core-ci-grpc
      Port: 3000
      TargetType: ip
      Protocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 10
      HealthyThresholdCount: 4
      Matcher:
        HttpCode: '200'
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
          Value: '20'
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
      VpcId: !Ref vpcId
  LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    DependsOn:
      - TargetGroup
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
  EcsCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Cluster'
    DependsOn:
      - LoadBalancerListener
    Properties:
      ClusterName: ecs-core-ci-grpc
  EcsTaskRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                # - ecs.amazonaws.com
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: iam-policy-ecs-task-core-ci-grpc
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ecr:**'
                Resource: '*'
  CoreGrcpTaskDefinition:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition'
    DependsOn:
      - EcsCluster
      - EcsTaskRole
    Properties:
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref EcsTaskRole
      Cpu: '1024'
      Memory: '2048'
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: container-core-ci-grpc
          Image: 'nginx:latest'
          Cpu: '256'
          Memory: '1024'
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: '80'
              HostPort: '80'
          Essential: 'true'
  EcsService:
    Type: 'AWS::ECS::Service'
    DependsOn:
      - CoreGrcpTaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref EcsCluster
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      DesiredCount: '1'
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 150
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 0
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: container-core-ci-grpc
          ContainerPort: '80'
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref CoreGrcpInstanceSecurityGroupOpenWeb
          Subnets:
            - subnet-34b92250
            - subnet-82d85af4
            - subnet-ca379b93
      TaskDefinition: !Ref CoreGrcpTaskDefinition
```

Comment: I also noticed i don't have dockerhub creds enabled, so could this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately AWS Fargate only supports images hosted in ECR or public repositories in Docker Hub and does not support private repositories which are hosted in Docker Hub. 
For more info - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=268415

Even we faced the same problem using AWS Fargate couple of months back. You have only two options right now:

1. Migrate your images to Amazon ECR.
2. Use AWS Batch with custom AMI, where the custom AMI is built with Docker Hub credentials in ECS config (which we are using right now).

**Edit:** As mentioned by [Christopher Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279147/christopher-thomas) in the comment, ECS fargate now supports pulling images from DockerHub Private repositories. More info on how to set it up can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-private-registry-authentication-support-for-aws-fargate/).

Comment: Hey raj, I was thinking that you could not use an ami with fargate, or are you saying that you have switched back to ecs rather than fargate.

Comment: You are right, we can't use custom AMI with AWS Fargate. We actually switched to **AWS Batch** (a different AWS service), where the EC2 servers are managed by AWS with an option to use custom AMI.

For more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/what-is-batch.html

Comment: AWS Batch has 3 components: `Batch environment` (where you define your machine specs), a `job queue` and a `Job Definition`(just like ECS task def). 


We call a lambda to submit a job to AWS Batch, which in-turn starts up a AWS managed EC2 server in ECS cluster where the docker image starts running. When the respective task is completed, EC2 will be terminated.


If you still want to use Fargate, you should migrate your docker hub images to AWS ECR (which would take very less efforts when compared to setting up new AWS Batch).

Comment: I did originally get a comment back from aws support that suggested that I can use private repositories.. However, after wasting my time they actually retracted that statement and said its not available for fargate

Comment: Just an update if anybody is reading this in 2020. This is now fixed and you can use private docker repositories just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do define this policy in your ECR registry and attach the IAM role with your task.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "new statement",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/ecsEventsRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Will this work even for a dockerhub image? In this example i am pulling the nginx repo but i will be wanting to pull our private dockerhub image once i get this working.

Comment: I also have a policy in that script which seems to cover these paths "ecr:**", unless this is a different context